# Converting timestamps of a MacOS file to Epoch

Tags: python, timestamp

I am inspecting time stamps of files created by `Ulysses App` (MacOS). Now I am trying to get the date-time for those time stamps. Here is what I see:

```
| Date Time                | Ulysses Timestamp |        Epoch | Epoch minus Ulysses ts |
|--------------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------|
| Fri, 2020-05-01 11:38:02 |         610018683 | 1588325880.0 |            978307197.0 |
| Mon, 2020-05-11 12:35    |         610886121 | 1589193300.0 |            978307179.0 |
```

So the delta is this:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(978307179)
# datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 59, 39)
```

Why Jan. 1st, 2001?  I reckon that MacOS / `Ulysses.app` is a `Swift` or Objective-C app. So how is Mac calculating timestamps? Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp seems to correspond to [Apple Mac Absolute](https://doubleblak.com/blogPosts.php?id=7#macabsolute). Unfortunately, at least I haven't found better, unambiguous, reason for different timestamps based on integers and seconds than just a matter of agreement (and avoiding integer overflow with timestamps having a more recent start). By the way Apple alone has 5 different timestamp formats — two starting from the 1st of Jan 1904 and three from the 1st of Jan 2001.